# Metric defined on the space of continuous functions

Tags: integration, metric-spaces, continuity

Let $d: C([0,1]) \times C([0,1])  \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ be defined as $d(f,g)=\left(\int_{0}^{1} (f(x)-g(x))^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$. Prove that $d$ defines a metric on $C([0,1]).$

$M_1,M_2$ were very straightforward. I am stuck on $M_3$, because I get to a point where I do not know how to split up the square root and get a lot of extra terms. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the special case of the [Minkowski inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality) for $p=2$: